# Chrome renders empty multiple selects smaller

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a situation where two `multiple select`s are next to each other and one of them starts out empty. I have set their heights using the `size` attribute.

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="10">
</select>

<select multiple="multiple" size="10">
    <option>option</option>
</select>
```

I noticed that Chrome renders the empty `<select>` slightly smaller than the one with content:

[image: two selects rendered differently]

Interestingly, the difference in height is the same as the value of the `size` attribute. In the picture I have `size="10"` and the empty select is exactly 10 pixels smaller.

I inspected the selects with Chrome's excellent inspector and found that the only different calculated styles between the two were `height`, `perspective-origin`, and `transform-origin`, with the last two being derived from the first.

I have a feeling this has something to do with some invisible placeholders Chrome uses when it calculates the heights. This is further supported by my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rk7vc87y/), where I created `<select>`s that are empty, have only `<option>`s, only `<optgroup>`s, and both, and then decreased the `font-size` of the `<option>` tag. The `<select>` with just `<option>`s in it got smaller, evidently because ten `<option>`s fit in smaller height. The one with both `<optgroup>`s and `<option>`s had to stay the same size to house ten `<optgroup>`s.

Trying to style the `<optgroup>`s yielded inconsistent results (i.e. IE) so I didn't try that.

Is there anything to be done to circumvent this? Both Mozilla and IE render the `<select>`s at the same height, so could it be a Chrome bug?

I know the obvious way would be to set the height with the CSS `height` attribute, or make them equal later with JavaScript. I would, however, like to continue using the `size` property for convenience and because this is exactly what it was designed for.

Answer (score 2):

> ...I have set their heights using the size attribute...

Actually you are starting it wrong. When you set the `size` attribute, you **do not** define the `height`. You are defining the number of `option`s instead.

From the specs here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-select-size

> The size attribute gives the number of options to show to the user.

There is a difference. The height is defined by the CSS `height` property. The HTML `size` attribute defines the number of options, which can change depending on the `font-size`s and `line-height`s.

---

> I noticed that Chrome renders the empty `<select>` slightly smaller than
>   the one with content

That behaviour should be expected. If there are no `option`s, then there are no intrinsic paddings or margins to be taken into account. When there is at least one `option`, the browser takes that into account. Hence, there would be a difference in the rendered/computed heights.

Also, when there is an `optgroup`, then the browser has to accommodate that as well to be able to show 10 `option`s as per the `size` attribute. Hence the computed height will be a little larger. It just has to show 10 `option`s even if one is partial, because it can show a scrollbar.

> Interestingly, the difference in height is the same as the value of
>   the size attribute. In the picture I have size="10" and the empty
>   select is exactly 10 pixels smaller.

That is just because you have set the font-size to 10 as well. Anyway, when there are no `option`s, then the browser can't compute the height and just renders the height based on the base font-size.

> The `<select>` with just `<option>`s in it got smaller, evidently because
>   ten `<option>`s fit in smaller height.

Now you got it.

---

> Is there anything to be done to circumvent this?

You should be using an appropriate CSS reset. If you use a framework like Bootstrap, it will be taken care of for you.

You could start from here:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/rk7vc87y/3/**

**Snippet:**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
div { margin: 32px; }
select { 
  width: 100px; vertical-align: top; 
  font-size: 11px; line-height: 11px; 
}
```

```html
<div>
    <select multiple="multiple" size="10"></select>
    <select multiple="multiple" size="10">
        <option>option</option>
    </select>
    <select multiple="multiple" size="10">
        <optgroup label="optgroup"></optgroup>
    </select>
    <select multiple="multiple" size="10">
        <optgroup label="optgroup">
            <option>option</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
```

---

> Both Mozilla and IE render the s at the same height, so could
>   it be a Chrome bug?

I would say, it is the other way 'round, perhaps!

---

### Edit

If you want to get it to display pixel perfect across all browsers, then you will have to set the `height` via CSS.

Particularly for Chrome, the default user-agent-stylesheet, defines the `min-height` of an `option` as `1.2em`. So, it would be helpful for you to override that while the setting the height of the `select`.

**Fiddle 2: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/rk7vc87y/4/**

**Snippet 2:**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
div { margin: 32px; }
select { width: 100px; height: 11em; vertical-align: top; }
option { font-size: 0.9em; min-height: 1.1em; height: 1.1em; }
```

```html
<div>
    <select multiple="multiple" size="10"></select>
    <select multiple="multiple" size="10">
        <option>option</option>
        <option>option</option>
        <option>option</option>
        <option>option</option>
        <option>option</option>
        <option>option</option>
        <option>option</option>
        <option>option</option>
        <option>option</option>
        <option>option</option>
    </select>
    <select multiple="multiple" size="10">
        <optgroup label="optgroup"></optgroup>
    </select>
    <select multiple="multiple" size="10">
        <optgroup label="optgroup">
            <option>option</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Good point regarding `size`/`height`, that was a semantical error from me. I did not, however, set the `font-size` in my example; in fact, there were no styles at all, I made it to show the default rendering (the styled elements are below). I do appreciate your effort, but your example actually made it a bit worse as Chrome now has three different heights for the four selects. They do remain equal in Mozilla and IE however.

Comment: @Antti29: The browser inconsistencies is something we will have to live with (yes even in 2015). Ideally, default styling should be rest via a proper css reset in order to make things look the same in all browsers. Moreover, in this case you would be better off by actually specifying a height via css.

Comment: @Antti29: I have edited the answer and added the Chrome specific points. Especially that Chrome default's `option` tag's `min-height` to `1.2em`. So you would be better off overriding that and also keep your `height` in `em` units.

Comment: The heights are now equal, but they no longer align with the number of options set with `size` in any browser. I just can't win, can I? I think my best bet is to check if the heights aren't equal, and then make them so, since this only affects Chrome.

Comment: @Antti29: The best you can get is with a proper css reset. That way you have different heights only when `optgroup` is involved. Otherwise you get consistent heights. [(See this fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/rk7vc87y/6/). You may also want to read thru [(this discussion here)](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=456555) to get some more insight.